# Zend passing server url / parameter to javascript file

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

For my application I need to pass a parameter through zend to my exter javascript file.
I need the server url in the javascript with the language parameter.

my javascript is placed in /js/javascript.js

I've tried the follow

layout.phtml

```
$this->headScript()
    ->prependScript('BASE_URL = "test";')
    ->appendFile('/js/javascript.js');
```

javascript.js

```
var url = BASE_URL
```

But my firebug console keeps saying that BASE_URL is not defined. What
is the good way to do this?

Regards.

Nicky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you include javascript.js, and just after it you prepend script before appended javascript.js.

```
$this->headScript()
     ->appendFile('/js/javascript.js')
     ->prependScript('BASE_URL = "test";');
```